# How do I login without an OpenID account?

Tags: support, openid, login, deleted-accounts, myopenid

I registered a Stack Overflow account with a [MyOpenID](http://myopenid.com/) account, and I deleted the MyOpenID account. So, I cannot log into the Stack Overflow account. I have tried to re-register MyOpenID account, but failed.

How do I login without MyOpenID (use email)? Or, how do I delete the Stack Overflow account?

The Stack Overflow account is not associated with my current account.

Comment: Your Meta account appears to be correctly associated with your Stack Overflow account, so you should just be able to log in the same way you logged in to Meta.

Comment: @Tim Stone, thanks! But the StackOverflow is associated with another MyOpenID account. I want to login and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send us an email (team@stackexchange.com) from the address associated with your old account and request a merge or deletion.

Comment: I sent an email for several days, but there is no replay ...

Comment: @iwill I can't find any emails from you. Which address did you send it from?

Comment: The email is sent from "the address associated with your old account", which begin with "jessige_27", and I re-sent it just now.

Comment: Hey @iwill, I found your email. It was apparently caught by the spam filter. Not sure why.